# Blazor FluentValidation pass rule to component

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, fluentvalidation

I using FluentValidation in Blazor Server and i have it working fine on a standalone component but im wanting to pass Rules to the component dynamically instead. Something like below:

```
<MyComponent Rules="MyCustomRules">...Text Here...</MyComponent>

@code {
    private FluentValidation.AbstractValidator<MyComponent> MyCustomRules()
    {
        RuleFor(field => field._value)
                    .NotEmpty().WithMessage(field => $"{field.Name} cannot be empty");
    }
}
```

Then the Rules parameter in `MyComponent` can apply the dynamic `Rules` to `MyComponent`. Is this possible? And how?

Comment: Why not just pass a data model with validation into the component?

Comment: Or you could pass an entire `AbstractValidator<MyComponent>` in the component.. that way you could define the rules outside the component as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestions below and a some further research, i have figured it out. As @Michal Diviš pointed out, i just passed the `AbstractValidator` as a `Rules` parameter to the component.

MyComponent code-behind:

```
[Parameter]
public AbstractValidator<TextField> Rules { get; set; }
```

Then in my page that consumes the component i create the rule and pass it into the component, `<MyComponent Rules="MyRules"`

```
Validation MyRules= new Validation();
private class Validation : AbstractValidator<TextField>
{
    public Validation()
    {

        RuleFor(field => field._value)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Field cannot be empty");

    }

}
```